# Is there a batch 'Bind' for EWS (CalendarView)?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I need to retrieve a users' calendar entries for a time period using Exchange Web Services.

I am using the `calendar.FindAppointments` API with a `CalendarView`.

When I use this api the items returned do not have all properties filled out (e.g. `Body`, `Categories`, and `Attendees`). Because of this I have to do the following:

```
CalendarFolder calendar = (CalendarFolder)Folder.Bind(this.Service, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar);
FindItemsResults<Appointment> findResults = calendar.FindAppointments(new CalendarView(startDate, endDate));

foreach (Appointment exAppt in findResults.Items)
{

  Appointment a = Appointment.Bind(this.Service, exAppt.Id);

  Models.Appointment appt = new Models.Appointment();
      appt.End = a.End;
      appt.Id = a.Id.ToString() ;
      ...
      appt.Notes = a.Body;
      ...
}
```

Note the 2nd `.Bind` within the loop.

This REALLY makes querying slow (it's already pretty horrible).

It takes MULTIPLE MINUTES to get about a dozen calendar entries!

I've looked but I can't find anything that will let me batch retrieve "full" items. Is there something like that I haven't found?

Maybe I'm doing something horribly wrong that is causing this performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out:

`this.Service.LoadPropertiesForItems(findResults, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ItemSchema.Id, ItemSchema.Body));`

But I still wish there were a way of specifying a `PropertySet` when defining a `CalendarView` as it would improve performance even further by reducing the number of round trips.

Comment: As per December 2013, you can, in fact, add a PropertySet to FindAppointments. Just that Body and Attachments and Organizer and Required and Resources and some other Properties are not or not fully returned, even if you request them.